# Blank Screen with Microsoft Remote Desktop

Tags: kali-linux, macos, remote-desktop, xrdp, rdp

I installed Microsoft RDP in my OS X to remotely access Kali machine using XRDP, but I am getting a blank screen when I tried to login using XRDP.

[image: Black screen with connection log]

Comment: Kelli is not a general purpose system. It's a specialist pentesting system, and as such it necessarily does things differently. I wouldn't have expected any inbound connection at all from RDP

Comment: Since I am unable to pay for Parallels, also the VMware tech preview version isn't really stable, I am using RDP for my work purpose and I am aware of the power and use of Kali Linux

Answer (score 2):

Issue -> The kali machine was unset of the opening window once after logged in from RDP, so when there was no screen it used to blank out and close the window automatically, So manually set the opening screen to HOME Screen.

---

Step 1 : sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh.
Step 2 : add the below commands in the shell file before the if statement

```
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
. $HOME/.profile
```

---

References : https://leoguides.com/how-to-fix-black-screen-remote-desktop-to-ubuntu-from-windows/

Once the changes are done in the host machine, it will work on any rdp client.

Comment: This worked for me - connecting to kali 2023.2 from macOS Monterey 12.6.5 (Macbook Air M2) using MS Remote Desktop.   The commands listed above are not properly formatted.  What worked for me is 3 lines:  (1) unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS (2) unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (3) $HOME/.profile.    (note StackExchange does not allow  me to edit answer today... too many edits)